# Cronjob not working with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to set cron job for one of my project and it works on my domain with sub folder named VMS.

I have created the cron job with controller:

```
    file:  main.php
   Class:  Main
  Method:  ExpiryAlertMail
Location: public_html/vms/application/controllers/main.php
```

I will try below listed method to run cron job but it give me different-2 error message with different-2 cases. So, how can I run my cron job once in a day?

> /usr/local/php4/bin/php /home//public_html/vms/index.php main ExpiryAlertMail
>
> /usr/bin/php  -q  /home//public_html/vms/index.php main ExpiryAlertMail  >> /dev/null
>
> /usr/bin/php /home//public_html/vms/index.php main ExpiryAlertMail
>
> /usr/bin/php /home//public_html/vms/index.php
>
> 0 13 * * * php home//public_html/vms/index.php main/ExpiryAlertMail
>
> php /home//public_html/vms/cron.php /main/ExpiryAlertMail
>
> ~/public_html/vms/index.php main ExpiryAlertMail
>
> wget http://www.domain.com/vms/main/ExpiryAlertMail
>
> php -q /home//public_html/vms/index.php?c=main&m=ExpiryAlertMail
>
> /usr/bin/php-cli  /home//public_html/vms/index.php main ExpiryAlertMail 
>   php /home//public_html/vms/cron.php main/ExpiryAlertMail
>
> wget -O - -q -t 1 http://www.domain.com/vms/cron/run

Comment: What are the error messages you get?

Comment: Case :php /home/user name/public_html/vms/cron.php /main/ExpiryAlertMail
msg: You dont have access to this page, Please contact Admin! 

Case :php home/username/public_html/vms/index.php main/ExpiryAlertMail
msg: You dont have access to this page, Please contact Admin!

Comment: Case: wget http://www.domain.com/vms/main/ExpiryAlertMail

Msg: HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 406 Not Acceptable
10:35:01 ERROR 406: Not Acceptable.

Comment: Case: curl '[domain.com/vms/main/ExpiryAlertMail]';
Msg: curl: (3) [globbing] illegal pattern or range specification after pos 2

Comment: The first two messages point out some problem with your server configuration or the application. Can you open the URLs with your browser without additional restrictions (like javascript or cookies)? The third message indicates that the server cannot return the requested data in a way you specified as acceptable (using `Accept` headers, eg. `Accept: application/x-shockwave-flash`).

Comment: Yes, i Know the format is not correct but i am hitting the url with browser then it works well. so let me know in which formet i need to send data

Answer (score 0):

If your script can be requested by url, you may try

> 0 13 * * * curl '[your script url]'

Comment: Case: curl '[http://www.domain.com/vms/main/ExpiryAlertMail]'

Msg: curl: (3) [globbing] illegal pattern or range specification after pos 2

Comment: @user3567380: It should be `curl 'domain.com/vms/main/ExpiryAlertMail'`, the brackets are meant to point out the placeholder.

Comment: Case: curl 'http://www.domain.com/vms/main/ExpiryAlertMail'
Msg: % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

100   372  100   372    0     0  50101      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 50101
100   372  100   372    0     0  49759      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
<html>
<head><title> 406 Not Acceptable
</title></head>
<body><h1> 406 Not Acceptable
</h1>
This request is not acceptable<hr />

Comment: Case: curl 'http://www.domain.com/vms/main/ExpiryAlertMail' > /dev/null

msg :   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

100   372  100   372    0     0   122k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  122k
100   372  100   372    0     0   119k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0

Comment: 406 means there is something wrong about your Web Service. What about visit domain.com/vms/main/ExpiryAlertMail in your browser?  What is the output.